# Load R packages when writing report with Knitr and LaTex

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I have the below combined systems for writing report with Knitr and LaTeX,

1. Rstudio Version 0.99.473 with R version 3.2.2
2. Knitr_1.11
3. MiKTeX 2.9
4. Windows 7

An example .Rnw code is shown below, my issue is that a text string "latticeknitrstatsgraphicsgrDevicesutilsdatasetsmethodsbase" was created right underneath "Figure 1: Test".  I wonder how to get rid of it.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\title{An example}
\author{Me}
\date{\today{}}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE>>=
knit_hooks$set(myPackage = function(before, options, envir){
  if(before)
    library(lattice)  else NULL
})
@

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{My section 1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Test}\label{fig:GofBase}
<<myPackage=TRUE, echo=FALSE, results='asis', cache=TRUE, fig.show='hold', fig.align='center', warning=FALSE>>=
xyplot(rnorm(100)~rnorm(100))
@
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Interesting, this works well if one loads lattice from outside the hook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the question is not very clearly formulated, and the minimal example is not absolutely "minimal", here a improved version:

### Question

Why does the following minimal example add a string like `latticeknitrstatsgraphicsgrDevicesutilsdatasetsmethodsbase` to the output?

```
\documentclass{article}

<<setup>>=
knit_hooks$set(myPackage = function(before, options, envir){

    if(before) library(lattice)
})
@

\begin{document}
<<myPackage=TRUE>>=
xyplot(rnorm(100)~rnorm(100))
@
\end{document}
```

### Answer

This has nothing to do with `lattice` and it's not a special feature of `knitr` chunk hooks.

#### What happens?

When a chunk hook returns a character value, this value is included in the output:

> In knitr, hooks can also be used to insert texts into the output. To do this, the hook function must return a character result. [[knitr: hooks](http://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/)]

In this case, there is no explicit return value of the hook. Therefore, the return value of `if()` is returned. `if()` in turn returns the value that `library` returns:

> `if` returns the value of the expression evaluated, or `NULL` invisibly if none was (which may happen if there is no else). [see `?"if"`]

And finally:

> `library` returns (invisibly) the list of attached packages [see `?libray`]

#### How to avoid it?

First of all, the example is not very good. There's no reason to load a package using a chunk hook. If `lattice` is required, it should be loaded in the `setup` chunk.

But there may be cases where a similar chunk hook *is* useful. Then, the solution is to explicitly return `NULL`:

```
knit_hooks$set(myPackage = function(before, options, envir){

    if(before) library(lattice)
    return(NULL)
  })
```

Comment: I want to justify why I loaded a package using chunk hook.  e.g., If `lattice` is loaded in `setup` chunk with `cache=TRUE`,  and `xyplot` function is used in a subsequent chunk, but with `cache=FALSE` and without calling `library(lattice)` in this chunk, then PDF can be successfully compiled for the first time, but if the same `.Rnw` file is to be executed for the second time, an error message will pop up complaining ` Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): could not find function "xyplot"`.  I think it is explained in [link](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/cache/)_...it is entirely OK to load..._

Comment: Hm ... I would say you shouldn't cache the `setup` chunk at all.

Comment: I agree with you that loading packages upfront in the chunk of `<<setup, cache=FALSE>>` allows the subsequent chunks to use  functions in all packages loaded early on, but I would say there is some situation where I need to load some specific libraries for a specific chunk, and another bunch of libraries for a different chunk,  it that case, chunk hook might be a choice... oh well, I might overdo it here.

Comment: Yes, this works and you may argue that there is some beauty in keeping libraries and code that uses those libraries together. On the other hand, this increases the complexity of your code and I wouldn't expect any performance advantages. But if your approach works fine for you, stick to it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimally changed version that "works for me" (also from RStudio)

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\title{An example}
\author{Me}
\date{\today{}}

<<setup, include=FALSE, cache=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
knit_hooks$set(myPackage = function(before, options, envir){
  if(before)
    library(lattice)  else NULL
})
@

\begin{document}
%\SweaveOpts{concordance=TRUE}
\maketitle
\newpage
\section{My section 1}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Test}\label{fig:GofBase}
<<myPackage=TRUE, echo=FALSE, cache=FALSE, fig.show='hold', fig.align='center', warning=FALSE>>=
print(xyplot(rnorm(100)~rnorm(100)))
@
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I added a `echo=FALSE` to the first chunk, and removed `results='asis'` from the second chunk.

Comment: Dirk, I copied your exact code to my system, and still got the same text string underneath "Figure 1: Test".

Comment: I didn't. Your code generated a four page pdf. Mine a 2-page.  In any even you already have a lot of bells and whistles in there.  Make it smaller and smaller until you understand what each component does.  Eg the dance around `library(lattice)` makes no sense.

Comment: I must confirm what @Yaming wrote. The code from the question and the code from your answer generates exactly the same PDF.

Comment: Ok, had another look.  Try setting `cache=FALSE` on the 2nd example. I'll edit my answer.  Sorry for the imprecision. (I also changed the first chunk to just do `library(lattice)` but that is immaterial...)

Comment: Sorry, still the same. However, I think the problem is solved.

Comment: Oh right, so it was the useless `if()` -- I removed that too.